# Is NSURLConnection unable to make HTTPS GET requests?

Tags: ios, ssl, https, request, nsurlconnection

I'm just doing exactly what I do for HTTP requests:

```
NSString *urlStrig = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mysite.com/search.json?param1=10&param2=String&param3=20"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStrig];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:Timeout];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"URL:%@\nResponse: %@\nStatusCode: %i\nError: %@", url, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode, error);
}];
```

But all I got is a 403 status code everytime. Testing it via curl in the terminal works fine.

Is there any problem between HTTPS and NSURLConnection?

Comment: Certificate issue? Are you getting and not handling an authentication challenge?

Comment: I kind of tried. I implemented `NSURLConnection` delegate. I don't know what to do when `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` is called.

Comment: this might help: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/nsurlconnection-with-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out that I had wrong key names in the URL. I'm such a noob :( Now I don't even need the NSURLConnection delegate methods.